# 2d balls not colliding properly

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection

I'm just trying to code a nice looking physics game.

The ball collision looks nice but if the balls are colliding too slow, they "stick" in each other. I have no clue why they do.

Here's my collision function:

```
private void checkForCollision(ArrayList<Ball> balls) {
    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
        Ball ball = balls.get(i);
        if (ball != this && ball.intersects(this)) {
            this.collide(ball, false);
        }
    }
}

public boolean intersects(Ball b) {
    double dx = Math.abs(b.posX - posX);
    double dy = Math.abs(b.posY - posY);
    double d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return d <= (radius + b.radius);
}

private void collide(Ball ball, boolean b) {
    double m1 = this.radius;
    double m2 = ball.radius;
    double v1 = this.motionX;
    double v2 = ball.motionX;

    double vx = (m1 - m2) * v1 / (m1 + m2) + 2 * m2 * v2 / (m1 + m2);

    v1 = this.motionY;
    v2 = ball.motionY;
    double vy = (m1 - m2) * v1 / (m1 + m2) + 2 * m2 * v2 / (m1 + m2);

    if (!b)
        ball.collide(this, true);
    System.out.println(vx + " " + vy);
    motionX = vx * BOUNCEOBJECT;
    motionY = vy * BOUNCEOBJECT;
}
```

But this is what happens when they collide with a low speed:
[image]

So do you have an idea?

EDIT:

The update of **Alnitak** works very nice... but one problem is still there... if i add gravity like this:

```
public void physic() {
    motionY += GRAVITY;                  // <= this part (GRAVITY is set to 0.3D)
    checkForCollision(screen.balls);
    keyMove();
    bounceWalls();

    posX += motionX;
    posY += motionY;
}
```

They still move into each other. I think this is the wrong way to add gravity, or isn't it?

And I think I did something wrong with the collision formula, because they don't fall right:

![image: falling balls]

and then they slowly sink into the ground.

**EDIT:**
found an AMAZING tutorial: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8a_GameIntro-BouncingBalls.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(m1 - m2) * v1 / (m1 + m2) + 2 * m2 * v2 / (m1 + m2);
```

This has an integer value 2. Please make it 2.0f or 2.0d then check it out. It must be the problem for small speeds. Becuse integer constant autocasts multiplied doubles.

If this does not work, then **Alnitak** 's answer would be helpful.

If you need real nice physics,  you should use the **force** then convert it to **velocity** then convert it to **displacement** . Look at integrator techniques like **Runge Kutta** and **Euler Integration**

```
Force-->acceleration-->velocity-->displacement
```

if collision occurs, just update the force then the rest will be flowing.

----> http://codeflow.org/entries/2010/aug/28/integration-by-example-euler-vs-verlet-vs-runge-kutta/  <-----

http://www.forums.evilmana.com/game-programming-theory/euler-vs-verlet-vs-rk4-physics/

http://www.newagepublishers.com/samplechapter/001579.pdf

http://cwx.prenhall.com/bookbind/pubbooks/walker2/

**Verlet integration** is a point between **Runge-Kutta-4** and **Euler Integration** preferably for molecular dynamics (a good example for bouncing balls if you ommit the electrical fields and bonds)

Comment: the 2 will automatically get promoted to a double in this expression.

Comment: Okay then i will read through some articles about Runge Kutta or how you would call it... because i read that Euler is not so good..

Would you recommend me some tutorials? because the wikipedia articles don't help me that much :P

Comment: FWIW, even if you use techniques such as this you still have to account for the fact that computer simulations result in _discrete_ position changes that can still "miss" the true collision point, causing exactly the problem the OP is trying to solve.  "Virtual" balls don't pass through every point between A and B when they get moved from A to B.

Comment: @TeNNoX: **Verlet algorithm** is not as hard as **Runge Kutta** and not errorful as **Euler Integration** . I used it as molecular-dynamics because it directly ommits velocity (goes directly from force to displacement but needs a displacement history for 2 iterations)

Comment: Here are nice examples: http://codeflow.org/entries/2010/aug/28/integration-by-example-euler-vs-verlet-vs-runge-kutta/ http://www.forums.evilmana.com/game-programming-theory/euler-vs-verlet-vs-rk4-physics/

Answer (score 9):

This is a common problem that happens because sometimes the delta-v of the bouncing ball is insufficient to take it back out of the collision zone.

So the collision routine reverses the direction again, taking it back inside the other ball, ad-infinitum.

You should add a sufficient offset (in the direction of the collision force) to the position of the ball to ensure that the newly calculated positions are no longer colliding.

Alternatively, check whether the balls *would* collide once you add the new `motion` values:

```
public boolean intersects(Ball b) {
    double dx = b.posX - (posX + motionX);  // no need for Math.abs()
    double dy = b.posY - (posY - motionY);
    double d = dx * dx + dy * dy;           // no need for Math.sqrt()
    return d < (radius + b.radius) * (radius + b.radius);
}
```

but you should also change `ball.intersects(this)` to `intersects(ball)`.

They may appear to collide slightly too early, but on a fast moving ball it probably won't be visible.

Comment: Yep, had pretty much the exact same probelm, only with squares, and that's how I solved it.

Comment: He should give the exclusion force a direction :) I solved this way ^^

Comment: Which would be the best way to do that?
I understand my problem... but i dont really know how to solve..
Moving the balls out of each other before calling the collide() method?

Comment: EDIT:
Will add that to the main post

Comment: @TeNNoX it's the same problem - your check for collisions with the walls isn't allowing it to bounce outside the zone where the collision is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found an AMAZING tutorial:
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8a_GameIntro-BouncingBalls.html